# Vim - How to position cursor automatically on first file or the file I am coming from in a (secondary) NerdTreeBuffer?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I haven't managed to figure out how to position the cursor on fourth/fifth line corresponding to the first file entry in a NerdTree buffer openend via `:ex .` (NERDTreeHijackNetrw=1).

Following line in my .vimrc doesn't work:

```
autocmd BufEnter * silent! if (exists("b:NERDTreeType") && b:NERDTreeType == "secondary") | <missing command> | endif
```

Comment: Do you mean the `NERDTreeFind` command?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. NERDTreeFind is a nice option, I wasn't aware of. However, it is not exactly I am interested in. I was just annoyed that I always have to move the cursor a few lines down to the first meaningfull entry when exploring the file system.

Comment: Are you using the arrows or `hjkl` to navigate the NERDTree listing? You should use `/foo`/`?bar` (and possibly `set incsearch`) instead. With that navigation method, the initial position of the cursor doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @romainl: `hjkl` is my preferred navigation method in a NERDTree window since the line is highlighted and I can scan visually through the available files. If I know a part of the filename I am looking for, I usually use the `ctrl-p`-plugin for that case. But I surely see your point. In my specific case I often have only 5-6 files in the directory and it would be sufficient to press a couple of times `j` to get to the file.

Comment: @Daan: is it possible to configure NERDTreeFind to open a NERDTree in the current window without opening a new one. If this is possible I think it would answer my question. I just have to think about a convenient invocation instead of `:ex .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying it in several ways, but the problem is that all of NERDTrees inner methods are private (they are defined with an `s:` infront of them, making it hard to re-use them), and also that hooking the BufEnter event is not very useful, because NERDTree does not seem to have been fully initialized yet when that event is fired.

At the moment, I think this would be the best solution:

```
fun! NewTreeOpen()
    NERDTreeFind
    wincmd o
    let g:NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1
endfun
```

What this does is:

- Opens a new NERDTree sidebar window with your current file selected
- Makes the NERDTree window the only window
- Tells NERDTree to close the (full-sized) sidebar again after you have selected your file

I hope that is good enough. Otherwise I think you should do a feature request to the author of NERDTree to ask if he can add this.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will go with it. (I've added following mapping: `nmap <silent><leader>no :call NewTreeOpen()<CR>`)